# how to sort priority queues in java

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

My program requires me to take data from two queues and sort them into a priority queue. The first queue is for planes landing and it takes priority over the second queue of planes trying to take off. I am having trouble understanding how to set up the priority queue and take the two separate queues and sort them correctly into the priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

A priority queue should be automatically orderered.
That is to say, when you poll it takes the least element according to the specified ordering (or natural ordering if none is specified). 
So if you want to use a priority queue, write a comparator so that the elements from the first queue get selected first (perhaps using a wrapper class).

A better solution might be to write your own queue. When polling from this queue, just check the first queue for available items, if none are available, check the second.